# Is it possible to auto update php.ini via a bash script?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, scripting

I'm trying to write an install script and i need to change the sendmail line in php.ini

but I want to do this automatically

at the moment I'm doing this manually:

- sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
- finding the line containing sendmail_path =
- then editing it to be
- sendmail_path = /usr/bin/msmtp -t

then saving the file.

Is it possible to just auto script this to make the change?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The better solution might be using something like augeas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^[^;]*sendmail_path/s/=.*$/= \/usr\/bin\/msmtp -t/' -i.bak /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

or

```
sudo sed -e '/^[^;]*sendmail_path/s/=.*$/= \/usr\/bin\/msmtp -t/' -i.bak /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

This is a `work by word` translation of your request to *sed commands*:

- open the file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
- find the line containing `sendmail_path` (whithout havin char `;` before)
- replace from the sign `=` to end of line by `= /usr/bin/msmtp -t`

**Warning** `-i` mean *inplace modification*. Using this will modify your **php.ini** (and create a *php.ini.bak*)

For *trying only*, don't use `-i` switch:

```
sed -e '/^[^;]*sendmail_path/s/=.*$/= \/usr\/bin\/msmtp -t/' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: thanks that's great, but do you know how i also uncomment the sendmail_path line in that command? the actual line i edit is ;sendmail_path= ... and i want it sendmail_path (without the ;)

Comment: I've tried this command: sudo sed 's/;sendmail_path = /sendmail_path = \/usr\/bin\/msmtp -t/' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  and it doesn't seem to update anything. I've also tried your command and it doesnt update.

Comment: also, this doesn't work or seem to do anything: sudo sed -i 's/;sendmail_path/blahblah/' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
  i think something is wrong :(

Comment: Ok this seems to work: sudo sed -i 's/;sendmail_path\s=.*/sendmail_path = \/usr\/bin\/msmtp -t/' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  thanks for your help